# How do i replace eval

Tags: javascript, security, browser, content-security-policy, unsafe

I have some existing code that looks like this.

```
i = new Function("obj", "_", s);
```

The parameter s contains an executable javascript code, as a string. At a later point in the method, it gets called like

```
i.call(this, e, v)
```

I get a csp error for unsafeeval for the new Function line. How do I resolve this such that the unsafe eval does not come up again? Please help.

Basically what I'm trying to do is, I have a third party application which I have localised to fix the eval errors for CSP.

Why does the new Function cause the unsafe-eval error?

Comment: Why are you building a function from a string? We need details on that to figure out how you get around needing to build a function.

Comment: what are you doing with this functions?

Comment: I've updated the question to give more details. @epascarello

Comment: Unless you have the strings built as functions ahead of time you are not going to avoid this error. The update really did not give any more details.

Comment: Why does the new Function cause an eval error?

Comment: Any technique that allows strings to be executed as code will give this error.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_eval_expressions

Answer (score 1):

As @James mentioned, `new Function("obj", "_", s)` evaluates the `s` part, and generates a function based on the string.

It really depends on what's the `s` here. Is it dynamically calculated?

- If no, then you can just copy the `s` as a real code:

```
const i = function(obj, _) {
  // paste s here
}
```

- If yes, you will have to explicitly list all possible implementations. For example:

```
const i = function(obj, _) {
  if (xxx) {
    // implementation 1
  } else if (xxx) {
    // implementation 2
  }
}
```